# Copiar la base de datos de mongodb del servidor al local

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

Quisiera saber como puedo copiar una base de datos (MongoDB) que esta en un servidor web a mi local.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mongo no tiene un metodo de backup?

Comment: Tienes acceso remoto al servidor de alguna manera?

Answer (score 0):

¡Buen día!

1. Si tiene acceso SSH o de cualquier otra forma a la línea de comando
   del servidor, ya tenemos un gran paso completado. Posteriormente
   puede ejecutar el siguiente comando:

   ```
   mongodump --db=nombreDeLaBaseDeDatos --out=/directorio/backup
   ```
2. En out se coloca la ruta en la que mongodb creará una carpeta con
   los datos del backup.
3. Posteriormente, descargue con ayuda de una conexión SFTP la carpeta
   que mongodb ha creado en su servidor. SFTP es un protocolo que
   permite el intercambio de archivos. Si no tiene un software que le
   permita usar SFTP le recomiendo utilizar Bitvise (en el caso de que
   tenga Windows)
4. Una vez la carpeta esté en su pc, abra la terminal y escriba lo
   siguiente:

   ```
   mongorestore --db=nombreBaseDeDatos --dir=/carpeta/backup
   ```

   dir es la ruta de la carpeta en la que está el backup descargado (es importante posicionarse dentro de ella)

¡Y listo! Ya la base de datos estará en su computadora.

¡Espero le sirva!

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería para el caso de no tener acceso SSH? ¿O si la Base de Datos es un **Sharded Cluster 4.2+**?